# Database connections (best practices)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have adopted the Repository/Service design pattern for my project and as I was building it, I thought to myself.

Would it be better to Get All the items for a repository (Hold it in the Cache) and then filter using LINQ rather than using a database connection for each call.

For example, I have this:

```
public Asset Get(int id)
{
    return GetAll().Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}

public IList<Asset> GetAll()
{
    return AssetData.Get(userId, companyId);
}
```

instead of:

```
public Asset Get(int id)
{
    return AssetData.Get(id, userId, companyId);
}

public IList<Asset> GetAll()
{
    return AssetData.Get(userId, companyId);
}
```

I figure that the first one would be best because it would speed up the system and there would be fewer database connections/queries.

So, can anyone explain to me which is the best practice for this scenario please?

Comment: The bigger question here is: what works best _for you_?

Comment: @Brian I think the bigger question here is what works best for performance.  I am interested to see the answers.

Comment: As Ken Schwaber would have said: "it depends".

Answer (score 4):

This is premature optimization. Until you start using the application you do not know where the bottlenecks are going to be. Wait till you start getting performance hits and then look at  what you can do to improve performance. You are also second guessing a proven technology that many services use on a daily basis. Databases are fairly robust and highly performant if treated right.

You have done the right thing by putting your repository behind an interface. This gives you the flexibility of changing your implementation without changing your consuming code. Consider using an ERM solution like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) that has [caching](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/24/nhibernate-2nd-level-cache.aspx) built in. There is no point reinventing the wheel that someone else has been refining.

Answer (score 2):

As @Brian commented the big question here is what works best for you and your particular scenario. I'd (personally) be wary of caching any application data that has a chance of going stale between requests i.e. a user has updated an asset record in your case but because it's cached your users won't be able to see the updates until the cache has expired or been refreshed (and that's just going to get confusing!).

I however used a similar technique to what you're proposing in a recent application where I used cached lookup data to populate description values in my return DTO. During testing this turned out to be significantly faster than the DB query joining across 10+ tables to get these values. The lookup data I used changed quite rarely but I expired the cache after 30 minutes just in case.

I think you also need to be conscious of premature optimisation and potentially trying to solve a problem that you may not actually have.